# Projection on the last inserted child

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
 select vrs.label as label1, 
        vrhs.label as label2, 
        vrh.inserted_at 
   from vehicule_request vr 
  inner join vehicule_request_history vrh 
     on vr.vehicule_request_id = vrh.vehicule_request_id 
  inner join vehicule_request_status vrs 
     on vr.vehicule_request_status_id = vrs.vehicule_request_status_id 
  inner join vehicule_request_status vrhs 
     on vrh.vehicule_request_status_id = vrhs.vehicule_request_status_id 
  where vrh.vehicule_request_id = 10133;
```

that displays:

```
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
| label1   | label2                 | inserted_at         |
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
| Traitée  | En cours de validation | 2011-10-11 14:17:32 |
| Traitée  | Demande d'informations | 2011-10-11 14:29:04 |
| Traitée  | En cours de validation | 2011-10-11 14:32:57 |
| Traitée  | En cours de traitement | 2011-10-11 14:33:57 |
| Traitée  | Traitée                | 2011-10-11 14:17:32 |
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

But first I would like it to display only the last inserted row

```
| Traitée  | En cours de validation | 2011-10-11 14:32:57 |
```

I thus tried this query

```
select
    vrs.label as label1, vrhs.label as label2, vrh.inserted_at
from
    vehicule_request vr
inner join
    vehicule_request_history vrh
        on vr.vehicule_request_id = vrh.vehicule_request_id
inner join
    vehicule_request_status vrs
        on vr.vehicule_request_status_id = vrs.vehicule_request_status_id
inner join
    vehicule_request_status vrhs
        on vrh.vehicule_request_status_id = vrhs.vehicule_request_status_id
where
    vrh.vehicule_request_id = 10133
group by
    vrh.vehicule_request_id
```

But it displays another row:

```
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
| label1   | label2                 | inserted_at         |
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
| Traitée  | En cours de validation | 2011-10-11 14:17:32 |
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

How can I tell it to order by the `inserted_at` descending ?

And second I would like to add a clause to only display the rows that have different labels.

It should display only this row:

```
| Traitée  | En cours de validation | 2011-10-11 14:32:57 |
```

The logic would be: if the label2 of the last inserted row differs from the label1 then display the row.

UPDATE: Sorry for being misleading, I had to rephrase the question as it was wrongly stated. Now I can get the last inserted row with the query:

```
select vrs.label as label1, 
       vrhs.label as label2, 
       vrh.inserted_at
from vehicule_request vr 
inner join vehicule_request_history vrh
   on vr.vehicule_request_id = vrh.vehicule_request_id
inner join vehicule_request_status vrs         
   on vr.vehicule_request_status_id = vrs.vehicule_request_status_id 
inner join     vehicule_request_status vrhs         
   on vrh.vehicule_request_status_id = vrhs.vehicule_request_status_id 
where vrh.vehicule_request_id = 10133  
order by vrh.inserted_at desc, vrhs.label desc 
limit 1;
```

It displays:

```
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
| label1   | label2                 | inserted_at         |
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
| Traitée  | En cours de traitement | 2011-10-11 14:33:57 |
+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

But I would like to make sure that this row is not displayed at all if its two labels happen to be identical.

For now, I can only display the error being there by adding a flag `(vrh.vehicule_request_status_id != vr.vehicule_request_status_id) as is_error,` to the projection:

```
+----------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
| is_error | label1   | label2                 | inserted_at         |
+----------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
|        1 | Traitée  | En cours de traitement | 2011-10-11 14:33:57 |
+----------+----------+------------------------+---------------------+
```

UPDATE: The `vrh.vehicule_request_id = 10133` clause is only here to avoid a massive display. But it shall be removed. So using a `limit 1` is not possible in fact.

Comment: *Please*, format your queries so we can actually read them!

Comment: `ORDER BY  vrh.inserted_at LIMIT 1`

Comment: how you define the first row ?.. sql  have not an implicit order ... so explain your criteria for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does allow you to `GROUP BY` one field and then `SELECT` different fields.

This, however, makes an arbitrary selection from amongst the group.  In theory *(though unlikely in practice)* each column could come from a different record.  It's only really useful when all the records in the group have the same value *(allowing you to group by a primary key, instead of every column)*.

In normal use either a column should be in the `GROUP BY` or it should be inside an aggregate function, such as `MAX()`, etc.

As mentioned in comments, it looks like you just need `ORDER BY vrh.inserted_at LIMIT 1`.  But even then you have TWO rows in your example data at the same `inserted_at`, so you'd need additional columns in the ordering.

```
select
    vrs.label as label1, vrhs.label as label2, vrh.inserted_at
from
    vehicule_request vr
inner join
    vehicule_request_history vrh
        on vr.vehicule_request_id = vrh.vehicule_request_id
inner join
    vehicule_request_status vrs
        on vr.vehicule_request_status_id = vrs.vehicule_request_status_id
inner join
    vehicule_request_status vrhs
        on vrh.vehicule_request_status_id = vrhs.vehicule_request_status_id
where
    vrh.vehicule_request_id = 10133
order by
    vrh.inserted_at,
    vrhs.label
limit
    1
```

That's a bit arbitrary, but at least you only get one record, and the same one record each time.

Or, in your case, should you get *two* records because they share the same timestamp?

Comment: If 2 records share the same timestamp then tough luck and I ignore this and only take one. By adding a `desc` to the `vrhs.label` ordering I can get the most interesting one. Now, if the last one happens to have the same label2 than label1 then I want the row not to be displayed.